# Mysql Nested query and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to perform the following query on my database :-

```
SELECT
source, Month as t1,
GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `reports` GROUP BY Month) as amount
FROM `reports`
GROUP BY source
```

To get the `source`, `month` and the `concatenated string` of the sum of the money that is obtained by the distinct source in 1 month. But I get a syntax error.

Comment: Are there 2 tables named `report` and `reports` or is it a typo?

Comment: You are using a harmful nonstandard MySQL hackstension to `GROUP BY`. Please read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: @Vatev they are the same

Comment: @mega6382 So should it be `report` or `reports`? Actually, if you could edit your post to make them what they need to be that'd be swell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you need, hopefully it is one of these two:

```
SELECT source, Month, SUM(amount) as sum
FROM reports
GROUP BY source, Month
```

The above, but grouped by source with the sums listed in one field:

```
SELECT source, GROUP_CONCAT(sum) as sums
FROM (
    SELECT source, Month, SUM(amount) as sum
    FROM reports
    GROUP BY source, Month
) as t
GROUP BY source
```