# How to perform GroupBy of a GroupBy in laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `reports` table which looks like something as follows:

Reports is monthly reports of users putting their efforts. It's many to many relationship table.

| id | user_id | project_id | total_effort | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 232 | 40 | 2023-01-23 |

I want to get all users with their contributions projects-wise so that I can create an excel something like this.

[image]

I am able to group users by group and get their collective data, but unable to group by project id as well.

So far here is my query

```
  $data = Report::select('user_id')
            ->selectRaw("SUM(total_effort) as total, DATE_FORMAT(report_for_date, '%b,%Y') new_date")
            ->groupBy('user_id')->with('userDetail:id,first_name,last_name')->get();
```

And this query return

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [total] => 500
            [new_date] => Dec,2022
            [user_detail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [first_name] => Hermione
                    [last_name] => Granger
                )

        )
```

But what I am actually looking for is something like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [total] => 500
            [new_date] => Dec,2022
            [projects]=>Array(
                [0]=>Array(
                    [project_id]=>1,
                    [total]=>30,
                    [project_detail]=>Array(
                            [id]=>1
                            [name]=>Project 1
                    )
                )
                [1]=>Array(
                   [project_id]=>41,
                    [total]=>30,
                    [project_detail]=>Array(
                            [id]=>41
                            [name]=>Project 41
                    )
                )
                [2]=>Array(
                    [project_id]=>32,
                    [total]=>30,
                    [project_detail]=>Array(
                            [id]=>32
                            [name]=>Project 32
                    )
                )
            )
            [user_detail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [first_name] => Hermione
                    [last_name] => Granger
                )

        )
```

So that I can loop the data and plot them in excel.
How can this be done? Even if it is just a Raw MySQL query how to do Groupby inside a groupBy?

Some reference that I checked but without any help

- [sql group by sub group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430408/sql-group-by-sub-group)
- [Mysql Nested query and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715130/mysql-nested-query-and-group-by)
- [using group function inside group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775668/using-group-function-inside-group-function)

Comment: have you tried to create plain mysql query and test it using either phpmyadmin, adminer or any other mysql editor ? if you have found what you need, than translate the result either to query builder or eloquent, and run it again, this time under laravel, either using test (best) or tinker

Comment: I haven't found anything, I have done the same thing as Abdualla mentioned. I am not sure if it is possible like that way in mysql. I am lacking in expertise  

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with()` method to load the relation with `groupby` clause

```
$data = Report::select('user_id', 'project_id')
    ->selectRaw("SUM(total_effort) as total, DATE_FORMAT(report_for_date, '%b,%Y') new_date")
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->groupBy('project_id')
    ->with('userDetail:id,first_name,last_name')
    ->with('projectDetail:id,name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, i can get relation data using `with`.  This query will give user and project list, but then again I will have to store the collection in the memory and loop though them,  to build user vs project matrix. 
Its kinda taking too much time and memory for data collection over 10k

Comment: @user7747472 why don't you use pagination?

Comment: I need to get all user vs project lists in an excel dump. So I need the complete dataset

Comment: might be best to use Query Builder `DB::table('reports')->select(user_id, user_details.first_name, user_details.last_name, project_id)->selectRaw() ... `  and use separate query to get all `$projects = Project::isPublished()->get()>keyBy('id')`  so you can use $projects[ $data->project_id]->name when needed inside your array list for excel dump , second suggestion is to use Job Queue to handle this process in background

Answer (score 0):

I would query the active projects within the reporting period and then use that to build up the main query with conditional aggregation (pivot) -

```
// get list of projects within reporting period
$projects = DB::table('projects p')
    ->join('reports r', 'p.id', '=', 'r.project_id')
    ->select('p.id', 'p.name')
    ->whereBetween('r.created_at', ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-31'])
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->get();

// build conditional aggregates
$columns = ['CONCAT(u.first_name, \' \', u.last_name) AS username'];

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $columns[] = "SUM(IF(r.project_id = {$project->id}, total_effort, 0)) AS project_{$project->id}";
}

// Add total column
$columns[] = 'SUM(total_effort) AS total';

$report = DB::table('reports r')
    ->join('users u', 'r.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->selectRaw(implode(',', $columns))
    ->whereBetween('r.created_at', ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-31'])
    ->groupBy('r.user_id')
    ->get();
```

The idea is to build and execute a query which looks something like this -

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS username,
    SUM(IF(r.project_id = 232, total_effort, 0)) AS project_232,
    SUM(IF(r.project_id = 233, total_effort, 0)) AS project_233,
    SUM(IF(r.project_id = 234, total_effort, 0)) AS project_234,
    SUM(total_effort) AS total
FROM reports r
JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id
WHERE r.created_at BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
GROUP BY r.user_id
```